# JavaScript code equivalent in ActionScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

Hi everyone I'm new in both languages... I found a example for scrambled numbers in JavaScript and HTML I would like to convert that code into ActionScript code, the languages looks similar for me but when I compile it in Flash Builder nothing happens... I would like to understand how to do the example but in ActionScript and MXML code...

JavaScript code parts that I don't understand how to do it in ActionScript:

```
function check(value)
{
    if ( value != Math.round(value) )
   alert("You must enter an integer in this input box.");
}
function generate( )
{
var minval = parseInt(**document.form.min.value**);
    if ( isNaN(minval) || minval != parseFloat(**document.form.min.value**))
```

---

And To implement this with TextInput in HTML:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="**min**" VALUE="" ONCHANGE="check(**this.value**)">
```

---

I don't know hot to leave it in AS3 and MXML... 
I tried:

```
public function generate()
{
var minval = parseInt(**min**);
if ( isNaN(minval) || minval != parseFloat(**min**))
{
```

and the MXML:

```
<s:TextInput id="**min**" change="**check(this)**" />
```

As you can see I'm very lost...

Comment: I don't understand what's with the ** ?  If you have never used either language before and you plan on using Flex I suggest you start with the "Getting Started" tutorials to at least get the gist of how things work. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/getting_started.html

Comment: @shaunhusain It looks like the problem is using the wiki syntax on StackOverflow. ** means bold - unless within a block of source code.

Comment: Please note that one of the biggest differences between JS and AS3 is that AS3 uses Strict Datatyping. This means that every variable and every function **must** be associated with a datatype. Functions are set up as `public function name( arg:DataType, arg2:DataType2 = DefaultValue ):ReturnDataType` and a variable is `var name:DataType = new DataType( '''constructor args''' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fx:Script>
```

`<![CDATA[`

```
import flash.events.Event;
import mx.controls.Alert;
public function check(event:Event):void
{               
        if (isNaN(parseInt(min.text)) || isNaN(parseFloat(min.text))) {
            /* Do something here*/
            Alert.show("Input a number", "Error");
        }               
}
]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TextInput id="min" change="check(event)"/>
```

This code works the way you want I guess.
Please bear something in mind that the parseInt function ignores any trailing non numeric characters after a valid integer. Say for example, the code works if you enter "a" first, but fails if u enter 1a. More details about the function can be found here

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#parseInt()

Comment: thanks that works better, although now I have problems with declaring the variables, like @Apocalyptic0n3 I need to use Strict Datatyping... I will appreciate if you know where can I learn it simple =) and thanks @ everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment:

The value of an input element is always returned as a string, so to check if the user has entered an integer, you should just see if the value is all digits, e.g.:

```
    var isInt = /^\d+$/.test(s); // '123' -> true, '123a' -> false
```

You may want to trim leading and trailing spaces first, or not.